Flutter/ Bad state: Headers already sent just audio package
I have an api thats needs Authorization header to get a song from id 'The api works fine and I don't want to edit it'.
I want to get the song to my flutter app it works fine after I load the song for a bit and then the app pause/crash for an exception:
E/flutter (26607): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Headers already sent
E/flutter (26607): #0      _HttpResponse.detachSocket (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:1218:35)
E/flutter (26607): #1      _proxyHandlerForUri.handler (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:3360:36)
E/flutter (26607): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26607): 

Here is my initState code:
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    List<AudioSource> source = [
      AudioSource.uri(
        Uri.parse(
            '${Apis.serverIP}/songs/load_song?id=${widget.songInfo.songId}'),
        tag: MediaItem(
          id: widget.songInfo.songId.toString(),
          title: widget.songInfo.songName!,
          artist: widget.songInfo.authorName,
          artUri: Uri.parse(
              '${Apis.serverIP}/song_avatar/${widget.songInfo.songAvatar}'),
        ),
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer ${widget.accessToken}",
        },
      )
    ];
    _playlist.addAll(source);
    _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    _init();
  }

  Future<void> _init() async {
    await _audioPlayer.setLoopMode(LoopMode.all);
    await _audioPlayer.setAudioSource(
      _playlist,
    );
  }

Please help
I tried asking the ai and it gave me this solution:
    await _audioPlayer.setAudioSource(
      _playlist,
      initialIndex: 0,
      // Set the headers here
      headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer ${widget.accessToken}"},
    );

But the headers is undefined in setAudioSource.
I think it got updated
